# C++ fill 2D array

Tags: c++

I am Java programmer. I'm trying to fill array in Win32 project

```
int **Data::matrixInitialize()
{
    int** MX = new int*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            MX[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }
    return MX;
}
```

But this code throw an exeption. Please help me to fill 2D array.

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: Do you have to use arrays? I would strongly recommend using `vector<vector<int>>` or at least `array<array<int>>` instead of raw arrays.

Comment: Your new only creates an array of pointers. You still need to allocate the integers themselves (more new). Better to use vector anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You miss an allocation:

```
int **Data::matrixInitialize()
{
    int** MX = new int*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        MX[i] = new int[n]; // Missing line
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            MX[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }
    return MX;
}
```

but it would be better to use `std::vector` or `std::array`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
#include <algorithm>

//...

int **Data::matrixInitialize()
{
    int** MX = new int*[n];

    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        MX[i] = new int[n];
        std::fill_n( MX[i], n, 1 );
    }

    return MX;
}
```